# Failed to write to partition Not Found (android, pixel 3)

Tags: android, flash

I make .img file for flashing pixel 3. 
Build is done perfectly. And I want flash.

When I make flash like this
 `fastboot flash boot boot.img` or
 `` ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT=`pwd` fastboot flashall -w ``

it shows Fail message
`target reported max download size of 268435456 bytes
Erase successful, but not automatically formatting.
File system type raw not supported.
Erase successful, but not automatically formatting.
Can't determine partition type.
FAILED (remote: variable not found)`

and

`writing 'boot'...
FAILED (remote: Failed to write to partition Not Found)
finished. total time: 2.506s`

please help me flashing this binary.
thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the boot image _isn't_ "done perfectly," since it shouldn't be in `raw` format. You also need to have your bootloader unlocked. And this isn't a question for SO.

Comment: @TheWanderer
what is the raw format? when i download pixel 3 original binary, it also has some xxx.img (like boot.img)
And bootloader is unlocked. log mentioned partition not found. I think problem is in device.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue and it led me to this thread. Make sure your adb and fastboot versions are up to date. You can get the latest version from [Here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools)